# E2Guardian+Squid mark forwarded packets between interfaces

Tags: iptables, proxy, squid

I read couple of similar scenarios but did not find any solution.

So this is what I have at the moment.

An Ubuntu 20.0 LTS box with E2Guardian 5.4 and Squid 4.10.
This host is set as gateway for my clients on network. There are four interfaces for my four networks. Every request (80,443) get DNAT-ed  and forwarded to E2Guardian 8080 or 8443 ports. After content filtering the requests get forwarded to localhost:3128 where a squid listening and forwards request to the real gateway.

My only problem is that all request are forwarded 192.168.1.253 as it's source ip. Therefore I can't filter/set up bandwith queueing and so one at my gateway per client(network) address.

I use the following script to set up routing and NAT. I mark every packets by their source net but I can't see the marks after E2guardian forwards the request to squid.
I set up tcp_outgoing_address in squid.conf but it's useless because squid get requests
from 192.168.1.253 ip where e2guardian forwards them to.

My goal is to adjust this setup to get requests forwarded to their proper way based the clients` network addresses.

A quick draft for better understanding.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16apWSLL8sX5T_VdDFMm7FMbseCMF41sr/view?usp=sharing

```
#!/bin/bash

LAN1_IF=ens160
LAN2_IF=ens192
LAN3_IF=ens224
LAN4_IF=ens256

LAN1=192.168.1.0/24
GW_LAN1=192.168.1.254

LAN2=192.168.2.0/24
GW_LAN2=192.168.2.254

LAN3=192.168.3.0/24
GW_LAN3=192.168.3.254

LAN4=10.15.0.0/22
GW_LAN4=10.15.3.254

PROXY_IP_LAN1=192.168.1.253
PROXY_IP_LAN2=192.168.2.253
PROXY_IP_LAN3=192.168.3.253
PROXY_IP_LAN4=10.15.3.253

ip route add $LAN2 dev $LAN2_IF src $PROXY_IP_LAN2 table admin2
ip route add default via $GW_LAN2 dev $LAN2_IF table admin2

ip rule add from $LAN2 table admin2
ip rule add to $LAN2 table admin2

ip route add $LAN3 dev $LAN3_IF src $PROXY_IP_LAN3 table admin3
ip route add default via $GW_LAN3 dev $LAN3_IF table admin3


ip rule add from $LAN3 table admin3
ip rule add to $LAN3 table admin3

ip route add $LAN4 dev $LAN4_IF src $PROXY_IP_LAN4 table admin3
ip route add default via $GW_LAN4 dev $LAN4_IF table admin3

ip rule add from $LAN4 table admin4
ip rule add to $LAN4 table admin4
ip route flush cache

PROXY_PORT=8080
PROXY_SSL_PORT=8443


iptables -F
iptables -F -t nat
iptables -F -t mangle

iptables -A PREROUTING -s $LAN1  -p tcp -t mangle --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -A PREROUTING -s $LAN1  -p tcp -t mangle --dport 443 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s $LAN1 -i $LAN1_IF -p tcp  --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port $PROXY_PORT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s $LAN1 -i $LAN1_IF -p tcp  --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port $PROXY_SSL_PORT

iptables -A PREROUTING -s $LAN2  -p tcp -t mangle --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 2
iptables -A PREROUTING -s $LAN2  -p tcp -t mangle --dport 443 -j MARK --set-mark 2

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s $LAN2 -i $LAN2_IF -p tcp  --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port $PROXY_PORT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s $LAN2 -i $LAN2_IF -p tcp  --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port $PROXY_SSL_PORT

iptables -A PREROUTING -s $LAN3  -p tcp -t mangle --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 3
iptables -A PREROUTING -s $LAN3  -p tcp -t mangle --dport 443 -j MARK --set-mark 3

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s $LAN3 -i $LAN3_IF -p tcp  --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port $PROXY_PORT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s $LAN3 -i $LAN3_IF -p tcp  --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port $PROXY_SSL_PORT

iptables -A PREROUTING -s $LAN4  -p tcp -t mangle --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 4
iptables -A PREROUTING -s $LAN4  -p tcp -t mangle --dport 443 -j MARK --set-mark 4

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s $LAN4 -i $LAN4_IF -p tcp  --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port $PROXY_PORT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s $LAN4 -i $LAN4_IF -p tcp  --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port $PROXY_SSL_PORT
```